# Failed to parse time string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I need to create a DateTime from the value received from a form. The problem is that the value is received like a string: "2016-10-10T08:29:06.959Z" and I need to received like `2016-10-10T08:29:06.959Z` without quotes, because if I receive with quotes I've got the next error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ("2016-10-14T22:00:00.000Z") at position 0 ("): Unexpected character

When I try to transform the value to a DateTime with:

```
$fechaHasta = new DateTime($params["fechaHasta"]);
```

If I try to use:

```
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y H:i:s", $data["fechaHasta"]);
```

I've got an empty object in $fecha2.

The form from where I send the data is:

```
<form id = "formSearch" class = "menu-table" method = "post" action = "<?php echo $this->basePath('/privado/actividades-planificadas/pai/exportdatatoexcel'); ?>">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "codigoPPM" value = "{{searchForm.codigoPPM}}" />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "fechaDesde" value = {{searchForm.dt1}} />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "fechaHasta" value = {{searchForm.dt2}} />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "estado" value = "{{searchForm.estadoSelected.id}}" />
    <button type = "submit">
        Exportar datos a Excel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img title = "Exportar tabla a Excel" src = "/img/logo-excel.png" />
    </button>
</form>
```

So, what I have to do to send the value without quotes or transform the value received in DateTime.

Comment: did you try removing the quotes?

Comment: How can I remove the quotes or send without quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = '"2016-10-14T22:00:00.000Z"';
=> ""2016-10-14T22:00:00.000Z""
```

---

```
$fechaHasta = new DateTime($date);
Exception with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ("2016-10-14T22:00:00.000Z") at position 0 ("): Unexpected character'
```

---

```
$fechaHasta = new DateTime(trim($date, '"')); /* « notice the trim */
=> DateTime {#174
     +"date": "2016-10-14 22:00:00.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 2,
     +"timezone": "Z",
   }
```

So you just trim the `"` away:

```
$fechaHasta = new DateTime(trim($params["fechaHasta"], '"'));
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

function `trim()` has option to remove specific characters from string:
e.g.:

```
echo trim('example"','"');
```

will output: **example**

Answer (score -3):

try strtotime function and you can set your required format as well.

example:

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime("2016-10-14T22:00:00.000Z"))

Comment: The problem was the `"`-quotes in the string, that need to be removed, before parsing. In your example $date would be `1970-01-01 00:00:00` because `strtotime` returns false