# How to fix 'Invalid datetime format' when import excel to database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, import, maatwebsite-excel

I'm import my excel to database using Maatwebsite Laravel excel. 
My excel has a date format column. When I import, the data will enter unless the value is a date format. How to fix it?
Column with date format is 'tanggal_bergabung' column.

Im using Laravel 5.8, Maatwebsite 3.1.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\DatabaseCompany;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class ImportDatabaseCompany implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new DatabaseCompany([
        //
        'kode' => $row['kode'],
        'bentuk_perusahaan' => $row['bentuk_perusahaan'],
        'company_name' => $row['company_name'],
        'kontak_perusahaan' => $row['kontak_perusahaan'],
        'grade' => $row['grade'],
        'order' => $row['order'],
        'industri' => $row['industri'],
        'jalan' => $row['jalan'],
        'rt' => $row['rt'],
        'rw' => $row['rw'],
        'kelurahan' => $row['kelurahan'],
        'kecamatan' => $row['kecamatan'],
        'kabupaten_kota' => $row['kabupaten_kota'],
        'provinsi' => $row['provinsi'],
        'tanggal_bergabung' => $row['tanggal_bergabung'], //value is datetime
        'status' => $row['status'],
        'id_sales' => $row['id_sales'],
        'sales' => $row['sales'],
        'id_captain' => $row['id_captain']

    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's either you change it to excel as yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s or input this on your date time

`\Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['tanggal_bergabung']))`

Comment: Error: Exception
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (43606) at position 4 (6): Unexpected character

Comment: You can try to use trim see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936763/failed-to-parse-time-string-in-php) for that error